# Linux Kernel : AXI interconnect, where and how is it handled?

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, hardware

I'm writing a Linux driver for my company in order to port our hardware to GNU/Linux desktops. I'm not a hardware guy at all and I'm struggling to understand how communication between the kernel and the hardware is made.

We basically have an AXI interconnect on which some IPs are wired (we are using Xilinx boards running PetaLinux).

I've already been able to send requests to the hardware, it works well but I feel like I'm missing something.
In the kernel I'm mapping physical addresses to virtual ones thanks to `ioremap()` and I made my own implementation of read/write like so :

```c
static void __iomem *mailbox;

static ssize_t mailbox_read(struct file *filp, char __user *buf, size_t count, loff_t *f_pos)
{
    ssize_t retval = 0;
    uint32_t mlb_data = 0; 

    if(down_interruptible(&sem))
        return -ERESTARTSYS;

    // *f_pos must be a multiple of 4
    // *f_pos must be in bounds
    // count must be 4 (mailbox supports only reading 4 bytes at a time)
    if(*f_pos % 4 || *f_pos >= MAILBOX_SIZE || count != sizeof(mlb_data)) {
        retval = -EINVAL;
        goto out;
    }

    mlb_data = readl(mailbox + *f_pos);

    if(copy_to_user(buf, &mlb_data, count)) {
        retval = -EFAULT;
        goto out;
    }

    *f_pos += count;
    retval = count;

out:
    up(&sem);
    return retval;
}

int mailbox_init(dev_t device)
{
    mailbox = ioremap_nocache(MLB_BASE_ADDR, MAILBOX_SIZE);

    if(!mailbox) {
        printk(KERN_ERR DRIVER_NAME ": cannot map mailbox, ioremap failed.\n");
        return err;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

On the user side, I try to read/write like so :

```c
int dev_fd = open("/dev/" DRIVER_NAME, O_RDWR);
if(dev_fd < 0) return whatever;

int data;
pread(dev_fd, &data, sizeof data, 0);

close(dev_fd);
```

It works great but I do not understand how can it be that simple, where is all the AXI stuff handled ? I thought that was something I'd have to do, but I was surprised to see everything works fine already.

I find it really nice that everything is transparent and all but the thing is I would like to implement some error handling and I have no clue on how to do it.

For example if I try to use [devmem](https://github.com/brgl/busybox/blob/master/miscutils/devmem.c) (which uses [/dev/mem](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/drivers/char/mem.c) internally) to read from an unsupported address, I get a bus error :

```c
root@petalinux:~# devmem 0xCAFEBABE
Bus error
```

But if I try to do the same through my own character device, it just hangs. No SIGBUS seems to be received.

**I'm not sure I've been very clear so to recap here are my 2 questions :**

- Where is handled the AXI stuff in the Linux Kernel ? Could it be a Xilinx driver "overriding" mine ?
- How to handle hardware failure like `/dev/mem` does by sending a SIGBUS to the userland app ?

Comment: I suppose as far as Linux is concerned, the "AXI stuff" just consists of reading/writing the mailbox registers and the rest is done in hardware logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Looking at the Xilinx AXI Ethernet Driver ([drivers/net/ethernet/xilinx/xilinx_axienet_main.c](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/drivers/net/ethernet/xilinx/xilinx_axienet_main.c)), setting up the iomem cookie (`mailbox`) causes `readl()`, `writel()`, `memcpy_fromio()` et cetera to handle the access properly.

   The details of how this is done at the hardware level, depends on the hardware architecture.  For example, mach-ipx4xx uses [__is_io_address()](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/arch/arm/mach-ixp4xx/include/mach/io.h#L357) macro to determine whether [ipx4xx_pci_read()](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/arch/arm/mach-ixp4xx/include/mach/io.h#L336) (via `inl()`) or [__raw_readl()](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/arch/arm/include/asm/io.h#L110)/[__indirect_readl()](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/arch/arm/mach-ixp4xx/include/mach/io.h#L198) should be used.
2. `loff_t` is signed, and it probably makes more sense to return -EFAULT rather that -EINVAL when the offset is invalid:

   ```c
   // *f_pos must be within bounds
   if (*f_pos < 0 || *f_pos >= MAILBOX_SIZE) {
       retval = -EFAULT;
       goto out;
   }

   // *f_pos must be a multiple of 4, and
   // count must be 4 (mailbox supports only reading 4 bytes at a time)
   if ((*f_pos & 3) || count != sizeof mlb_data) {
       retval = -EINVAL;
       goto out;
   }
   ```
3. Instead of `readl()`, consider using the newer `ioread32()` (or `ioread32be()`, if the device always uses big-endian byte ordering).  See [include/asm-generic/iomap.h](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/include/asm-generic/iomap.h) for details.

   On many architectures, `ioread32()` does just call `readl()`, so this is not a functional change; this is more about being easier to maintain in the long term, by keeping up with the currently recommended internal kernel interfaces.

   (The comment that "[certain] architectures cannot use this generic interface" is directed to architecture maintainers, that they cannot just rely on the generic interface, but need to implement the macros for their hardware architecture in arch-specific files.  Driver developers can rely on these macros being available and working correctly.)
4. Raising SIGBUS here does not really make sense, since the userspace is not trying to access memory directly, but use a syscall; returning -EFAULT is definitely more appropriate here.  However, to raise SIGBUS, you do

   ```c
   struct kernel_siginfo info;

   clear_siginfo(&info);      // Important! So you don't leak to userspace.

   info.si_signo = SIGBUS;
   info.si_code = BUS_ADRALN; // Reason, see include/uapi/asm-generic/siginfo.h
   info.si_errno = 0;
   info.si_addr = addr;       // Address of the error
   info.si_addr_lsb = lsb;    // Least significant bit of the address

   force_siginfo(&info);
   ```

I hope this helps, and that you'll push your GPL driver upstream, even if there are only a few users.  Greg KH in particular has helped with such work in the past.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your amazing answer, I didn't expect that good of an answer ! If you will I still have a few questions left for you :

Comment: Regarding your first point: can I safely asume that the AXI stuff will already be handled on our clients machines or should I embed AXI communication routines within my driver ?

Comment: Regarding your fourth point: our hardware interface has some readonly registers and if we try to read those the hardware will raise a slave error which will return an AXI error back to the host. What I don't understand is how to tell the userland "something went wrong with the hardware" as I have no control over AXI communication (and its error bits). I thought a SIGBUS would be approriate but if you have a better idea let me know. What I don't get is that devmem is able to catch the error while my userspace app just hangs...

Comment: When I try to read this read-only register I get the following in the kernel ring buffer : `Internal error: synchronous external abort` followed by a stack trace showing that it failed on the `ioread32()`. How to catch that error and fail smoothly ?

Comment: @ShellCode: What do you mean by "AXI communication routines"? AXI itself is something that memory-maps registers on master devices to slave devices; and the AMBA AXI4 spec defines the hardware-level protocol. AFAICS, there is no "communication protocol"; just writing to the registers, as the hardware does all the AXI4 protocol stuff itself.  (That said, I have never developed anything related to AXI myself.)

Comment: @ShellCode: The AXI stuff in kernel uses IO ports, while devmem just (tries to) read and write ordinary RAM, not IO. (Yes, IO ports can be memory-mapped, but you didn't try to access memory-mapped registers when you got SIGBUS.  If the hardware was such that devmem could read the memory-mapped registers, it too would die with the same synchronous external abort.) So, the two are not at all comparable.

Comment: @ShellCode: Synchronous external abort occurs when the ARM CPU raises an exception (a hardware condition, nothing to do with C or C++).  You should be able to use [arch/arm/mm/fault.c:hook_fault_code(16, yourfunc, SIGBUS,  0, "synchronous external abort")](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/arch/arm/mm/fault.c) where `yourfunc()` simply returns 0 and sets an error flag if the first address is in kernel code, and a "active axi operation" flag is set; 1 otherwise.  Your code sets the latter flag before doing an AXI access, clears it afterwards, and checks the error flag.

Comment: (The 16 is because that's the index to the [arch/arm/mm/fsr-3level.c:fsr_info](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/arch/arm/mm/fsr-3level.c) array that has that "synchronous external abort" error.  Apparently, 16 is the exception identifier the hardware gives for AXI data errors, so this is the one you need to divert during those accesses.)

Comment: Again, thanks for your time, it's very helpful. The AXI stuff is clearer now, what is not however, is how I should handle its errors. `hook_fault_code` looks great but is only available for arm and not arm64 (which I'm using). I found a similar function in the arm64 headers called `hook_debug_fault_code` but I've not been able to use it, I get `Unknown symbol hook_debug_fault_code (err -2)` in dmesg. Plus, this is architecture specific, I was hoping for something more generic...

Comment: devmem enables you to mmap physical addresses, is it really not comparable to an ioremap done in the kernel ? I mean there're both translating physical addresses to virtual ones through VMAs, right ? Even if there are somehow different, I'm trying the access the exact same hardware register, on one hand I have a userland error, on the other hand I have an external abort in the kernel... I simply don't get it

Comment: On ARM64, it's the 16th entry in the [arch/arm64/mm/fault.c:fault_info](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/arch/arm64/mm/fault.c#L733)[] array. When it occurs, the do_sea() function gets called; that one calls [arch/arm64/kernel/traps.c:arm64_notify_die()](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/arch/arm64/kernel/traps.c#L197).  *If the code that causing the fault was running in userspace, that process is killed; but if the code was in kernel, you get an oops.*  Because the array is `static const` on arm64, we cannot modify it.

Comment: Your userspace code seems to "hang" because of the oops: the execution of that syscall is just stopped at that faulting instruction, and the kernel never gets back to it; so the userspace process will wait forever for the syscall to return – but it never will. This is the difference between doing the accesses in an external process (devmem) and in the kernel.  As to how to solve this, I believe you need to filter the addresses in your driver, so that this cannot occur.  Otherwise, you need to contact LKML or linux-arm-kernel for modifying arch/arm64/mm/fault.c.

Comment: @ShellCode, for Arm64 hardware no need to use `ioread*()` family of functions. This bad advice or myth circles around for too long. The new hardware is almost never will be used on I/O (vs. MMIO), except some intrinsic one which is solely for the certain architectures. With `readl()`/`writel()` et. al your code will look better.

Comment: Yes, @0andriy is right: better make sure your code is not portable across hardware, and that "it looks better".  Ignore that `long` is 64-bit on 64-bit hardware, but `readl()`/`writel()` only read 32 bits.  Functionality isn't important at all, looks is what matters.  I'm out; goodbye.

Comment: @Glärbo, huh? Tell me when last time you saw ARM with IO port? Or maybe RiscV? Or ? Seems you completely missed my point.